# Vector building optimization using std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, move

I'm building some `std::vector<Obj>` where `Obj` are large objects which can be move constructed and assigned (think eg of `Obj` being large vectors). The code is typically a loop such as

```
std::vector<Obj> v;
while (...) {
    Obj foo = some client code(...);
    // ... some complicated stuff modifying foo
    v.push_back(foo);
}
```

As you can see, `foo` is not needed after being pushed in the vector.

My questions are

- Does is make sense to write

  ```
    v.push_back(std::move(foo));
  ```

  to indicate to the compiler that it can take the contents of foo.
- if it does, is it actually needed ? Indeed the compiler might notice that `foo` is destructed right after being pushed so that it can be moved... Does actual compilers use those kinds of optimisation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not allowed to call the move constructor or elide the objects without you explicitly moving (ie, casting to an rvalue reference; possibly by std move) except under very specific situations.

A) the object is a temporary unnamed object.

B) The object is being returned from a function.

There are a few other requirements, but neither of the above two apply here.  So no conversion to move/elision allowed.

The complier can sometimes use the as-if rule to turn a copy and later destroy into a move, but that is very difficult and often fragile, so you should not ever rely on it.

Comment: So I should definitely add the move ! Thanks for these clarifications !

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not the compiler can optimize it depends on exactly what `Obj` looks like, what functions you call when doing "complicated stuff modifying `foo`", whether `Obj` has a move constructor, and so on. You should try to compile and benchmark the code and see for yourself, or use an online service like https://godbolt.org/ to see what assembler code is produced.

However, the best way is to avoid copying or moving altogether. You can do this by calling [`emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to construct an `Obj` directly in the vector, and then modify it in place, like so:

```
while (...) {
    v.emplace_back();
    Obj &foo = v.back();
    // ... some complicated stuff modifying foo
}
```

And you can write this slightly shorter with C++17:

```
while (...) {
    Obj &foo = v.emplace_back();
    // ... some complicated stuff modifying foo
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Two comments : you didn't answer the first question: is it useful to do the std::move by myself ? In particular, in my case, foo is constructed by some client code (see my edit), so I can't decide where it is constructed. Sorry if my question wasn't specific enough.

Comment: Answering my own comment... I just realize that I can do  `v.emplace_back(some client code());` so the second part of my comment doesn't make taht much sense. I'm still interrested to the answer of the first question.

Comment: @hivert I really cannot answer the first question without knowing more about `Obj`. For example, if `Obj` was just an `int`, then of course `std::move()` wouldn't have any effect. If it's something with a move constructor, then it might be, since `push_back()` does have an overload for r-value references.